# Faà Di Bruno formula derivative question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to compute the $n$-th derivative of $[f(x)]^k$ using the Fa di Bruno formula.
I have an expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$, in place, but I would like to treat the power $k$ as another function to compose $f(x)$. Therefore, I am treating $g(x) = x^k$ and then arriving at $[f(x)]^k = g(f(x))$. I will then set up the Faà Di Bruno formula as
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}g(f(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^nf^{(i)}(g(x))\text{B}_{n,i}\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x), \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x),\dots\right)
\end{equation}
where $\text{B}_{i,j}$ are the Bell polynomials. Is this the correct way to proceed? I am not sure about treating a power as a composition. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's $g^{(i)}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)$ after the sum sign. The derivatives of $y\mapsto y^k$ are easy to compute.